# Column value of first table needs to be update automatically whenever the second table row is updated or added

Tags: mysql, sql

Column value of first table needs to be update automatically whenever the second table row is updated or added.

I have two table `CcnCSR` and `CsrTimeReporting`

```
mysql> select * from CcnCSR;      
 select * from CsrTimeReporting;

+-----------+-----------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+--------+
| CSRNumber | Slogan                                  | Severity | Customer    | Status    | CreatedDate | CcnQDate   | TTS        | IAdate     | TotalTimeReported | Remark |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+--------+
|   2718122 | DIAMETER LINK FLICKS BETWEEN GGSN-CCN38 | High     | IdeaIndia   | NULL      | 2105-03-04  | 2105-03-03 | 2015-03-28 | 2105-03-13 |              NULL | NA     |
|   2718133 | Auto ZR                                 | High     | AirtelIndia | Analysing | 2105-03-20  | 2105-03-23 | 2105-04-10 | NULL       |              NULL | NULL   |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+--------+
```

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

```
+-----------+-------+------------------+--------------+-------+
| CSRNumber | SeqId | TimeReportedDate | TimeReported | Shift |
+-----------+-------+------------------+--------------+-------+
|   2718122 |     1 | 2015-03-15       |            8 | NULL  |
|   2718122 |     2 | 2105-03-03       |          0.5 | NULL  |
|   2718122 |     3 | 2105-03-03       |            3 | NULL  |
|   2718122 |     4 | 2105-03-03       |          4.5 | NULL  |
|   2718122 |     5 | 2105-03-03       |         5.25 | NULL  |
|   2718122 |     6 | 2105-03-05       |         7.25 | NULL  |
|   2718133 |     8 | 2015-03-30       |            2 | NULL  |
|   2718133 |     9 | 2015-03-31       |          2.5 | NULL  |
|   2718133 |    10 | 2015-03-29       |          3.5 | NULL  |
+-----------+-------+------------------+--------------+-------+
```

9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Where in table `CcnCSR` there is column "TotalTimeReported", this column value needs to be update automatically whenever the second table column "TimeReported" is updated or new row is added.

How can i do this?

Comment: Create a trigger. In mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html . In sql-server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: [Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) is what you're looking for

Comment: of course you can, use `trigger`, try and if you couldn't or get errors or have problems then come with what you tried and ask,

Comment: In case it did not mention you can use trigger!!! -:)

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you can do it**

```
create trigger trigger_name
on CsrTimeReporting
for insert
as
begin
declare 
@time_reported decimal,
@CSR_Number nvarchar(50) -- select data type as you need

select @CSR_Number = CSRNumber , @time_reported = TimeReportedDate from 
CsrTimeReporting              

Update CcnCSR set TotalTimeReported = @time_reported where 
CSRNumber = @CSR_Number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using multiple triggers, one for `insert`, `update`, and `delete`:

```
delimiter //
create trigger trig:csrTimeReport_insert on CsrTimeReporting
    after insert for each row
begin
    update CcnCSR
        set TotalTimeReported = TotalTimeReported + new.TimeReported
        where CcnCSR.CSRNumber = new.CSRNumber;
end;//

create trigger trig:csrTimeReport_update on CsrTimeReporting
    after update for each row
begin
    update CcnCSR
        set TotalTimeReported = TotalTimeReported + new.TimeReported - old.TimeReported
        where CcnCSR.CSRNumber = new.CSRNumber;
end;//

create trigger trig:csrTimeReport_delete on CsrTimeReporting
    after delete for each row
begin
    update CcnCSR
        set TotalTimeReported = TotalTimeReported +  - old.TimeReported
        where CcnCSR.CSRNumber = old.CSRNumber;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort ...
When i try to insert /update it giving below error 

insert into CsrTimeReporting (CSRNumber,TimeReportedDate,TimeReported) values (2718133,20150317,8);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'CcnCSR' in 'where clause'

All i need is the value of sum(TimeReported) from CsrTimeReporting where CSRNumber=2718122; 
want to be the value of column  "TotalTimeReported" at CcnCSR table
where the CSRNumber=2718122

Comment: @MohamedAshraf . . . I seem to have put in the table name instead of both the table and column.